Powerpoint Vsto Addin not closing powerpoint application
Application.Quit is not working from inside powerpoint VSTO Addin.
I checked it also with an empty project with one button and one event:
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Quit();
        }

Also tried:
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Presentations);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Quit();

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

None of these worked.

can you explain more on what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to close the PowerPoint or the task pane?
